# What's the proper way to add a single React Native view to an existing Android application?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on a large existing Android and iOs project, and my team would like to adopt react native. At first, We would like implement a single feature in RN since we don't have the capacity to migrate the whole project at once.

I've managed to add an RN view successfully, both from a local node server and from a JS bundle file located in the assets folder but it feels a bit hacky. I know this is supported on iOs but I couldn't find any thing in the docs regarding integration with an existing Android project. Here's the gist of what I came up with:

```
public class ReactNativeView extends FrameLayout {

    private static final String COMPONENT_NAME = "AwesomeProject";
    // Path of our RN module relative to project root
    private static final String MODULE_NAME = "react-sources/index.android"

    public ReactNativeView(Context Context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        ReactInstanceManager.Builder builder = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(AppDelegate.sharedApplication())
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.BEFORE_RESUME);

        if (BuildConfig.USE_RN_LOCAL_SERVER) {
            // Set module name to be loaded from local node server
            builder.setJSMainModuleName(MODULE_NAME);
        } else {
            Uri uri = AssetsManager.getInstance().getJsBundleUri();
            // Load bundled jsBundle
            builder.setJSBundleFile(uri.getPath());
        }

        ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = builder.build();
        MainActivity mainActivity = MainActivity.getMainActivity();

        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ReactRootView reactRootView =
            new ReactRootView(AppDelegate.sharedApplication().getTopActivity());
        // Is it really necessary to call 'startReactApplication' each time we want to render a react component?
        reactRootView.startReactApplication(reactInstanceManager, COMPONENT_NAME, null);

        addView(reactRootView);
        // After the view is added to the hierarchy we call the manager's 'onResume' function
        // to show the react view
        reactInstanceManager.onResume(mainActivity, mainActivity); // <-- What kind of sorcery is this?!
    }
}
```

And I've also added a variable to the BuildConfig which determines which JS bundle to use:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_RN_LOCAL_SERVER", "true" // load from local server
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_RN_LOCAL_SERVER", "false"
    }
}
```

This is a complete hack. Calling `startReactApplication` when what I'm actually doing is simply adding a view to screen feels awkward. Am I missing an API or is this not a supported scenario yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently calling `startReactApplication` is indeed to correct way to go. If anyone's interested in a more complete and organised solution, you can take a look at [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation).

Comment: Hi,I was starting react-native component from application class and it was working fine until react-native version 0.64.0 where it suddenly stoped to start reactnative component from application class. My usecase only requires react-native to work in the background with no UI component. I wanted to access it from all the activities, so created it on app launch in the application class. Can you provide any thoughts about it.
https://github.com/ErManishPatiyal/NativeIntegration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71599216/how-to-start-a-react-native-component-from-andriod-application-class

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [RN official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-android.html#content) about this subject ?

It shows you how to cleanly run a RN view inside a Java coded Android app.

Comment: The docs show how to integrate a react view which is a root of a new app. There are no examples of how to add multiple RN views that share the same RN bridge (which is possible on iOS). There's an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1398) about this in the RN GitHub page.